# Session expiring after closing Chrome in Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, session-restore

Since last two/three weeks after closing Google Chrome in Windows, I'm getting logged out of all the websites I have logged in. Every time the session is getting closed for all websites when I reopen the browser. I am facing the same issue in Chrome on my work PC also. Earlier I never had this issue, were browser continues the sessions even after closing it.

Current version: Google Chrome: 61.0.3163.100

Is it a new feature after the update? If it is, how can I roll back to the previous mode were I could continue the sessions even after a restart of Chrome browser?

Comment: The settings in Chrome could have been tweaked to not save your passwords on default. Please go to Settings > Manage Passwords. Make sure it is on and Auto sign-in is enabled.

Comment: @GeorgeTian I think this is the solution. Anyway I reset Chrome and is working fine now. Now auto sign-in is enabled for me. Could you please update this as an answer to the question?